# Is there a way to add Services to the Trash Can's context menu?

Tags: services

I am wondering if there is a way to add custom Services to the Trash Can's context menu (specifically the context menu that appears when right clicking the Trash Can from the dock rather than in a Finder window.). The reasoning is that I've built a series of simple programs to replicate the functionality of the now-deprecated "Securely Empty Trash" option in Finder, but I don't want to put it up for download until it has a proper OS-integrated feel.

Answer (score 1):

In Yosemite and before, maybe (though exactly how is off-topic for this site), but specifically with El Capitan and forward, it's no longer possible to inject code into running processes, which is about the only way I can think of that you'd be able to override a system menu like that.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway. I've gone ahead and put an applet in the utilities folder upon installation instead